# How to start a web application with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I love eclipse and java. And i want to code my entire web application using eclipse .. right from designing html files to servlets.. I have zero experience in developing web apps .. So How to to setup eclipse for web apps and How do i get started ???

Answer (score 4):

[Google even autocompletes this question so you know it's a popular query!](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=creating+a+web+application+in+eclipse&btnG=Google+Search&aq=1&oq=creating+a+web+applicati&fp=9XpCdJbaSz4)

Comment: there is an update error coming when i try to install WTP via update site.. which i have posted it as a new question here .http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846685/eclipse-wtp-update-error-what-to-do-next

Answer (score 1):

There is very little information that you are providing, and there are actually tutorials for creating web applications with Eclipse and Java. You will want the JavaEE version of Eclipse as a starting point.

If you want to try using a web framework that works with Java I recommend Struts, although this may be too big if you're wanting to develop small web applications (and it's not exactly the easiest thing to start with).

I also recommend installing Apache Tomcat as your server because it's free and easy to use. Here's a good starting tutorial:

http://www.xwt.org/tutorial/eclipse/

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make sure you've got the Java EE eclipse binary : http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

As has been mentioned, there are various google-able tutorials on how to set up, deploy and manage web applications under eclipse.