# Eclipse WTP update Error . What to do Next?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I just unzipped the eclipse ganymede (eclipse 3.4.1) zip file (basic platform) and tried to install Webtools (WTP) via its update site. But it reports an error like ..

```
Cannot complete the request.  See the details.
WST Common UI is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
WST Common Core is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
WST XML Core is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
WST XML User Documentation is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Eclipse XML Editors and Tools is already installed, so an update will be performed instead.
Cannot find a solution where both Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.jpt.doc.isv/[1.1.0.v200812110000,1.1.0.v200812110000]] and Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.jpt.doc.isv/[1.0.0.v200805220000,1.0.0.v200805220000]] can be satisfied.
Cannot find a solution where both Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.jpt.feature.feature.jar/[2.1.1.v200902200210-7A79BjDZRDE7GUMQDJGD,2.1.1.v200902200210-7A79BjDZRDE7GUMQDJGD]] and Match[requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.jpt.feature.feature.jar/[2.0.103.v200901160200-793DyCYQCD5FVHgCMCC,2.0.103.v200901160200-793DyCYQCD5FVHgCMCC]] can be satisfied.
```

And this list continues to over 100 similar lines.. What should i do to recover and install WTP into my eclipse ganymede .. ???

Comment: i downloaded a new ganymede zip file from eclipse site.. and it works for me now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already looked at this?

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/faq/GettingSource/

There are different instructions for putting the WTP on Ganymede than the other versions of Eclipse.

Comment: yep. i know how to install something from update site... i just a basic eclipse platform setup and it says WTP software conflicts with existing software.. what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you also let it search the Ganymede site at the same time?